# Big image with many icon or one image one icon?

Tags: java-me, lwuit

I have to display around 100 icons (each 50x50) in Button. I am downloading big png Image which contains all 100 icons, then I create each icon using `Image.subImage()` method.

But my application getting `OutOfMemoryError`.

I am thinking about 2 solution for this:

1. download 100 icons as tar(combined into single) file. So i can
   create icon one by one. Big Image need not to be in memory till I
   create last icon.
2. Download big Image but don't create small icon.Then override Button
   class to paint image (icon) from big Image.

Which is the best solution? or do you have any other solution for this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LWUIT is designed for small devices, and so should you design your code. So a big image is not a good idea.

You should really use seperate images. and only keep those in memory that you can see. Or you will keep running into outofmemory errors.

I would handle it like this.
Get a cachemap.
if you want an image, check if it isn't already in the cachemap.
if it is, use the image from the cachemap
if it isn't download it and put the image in the cachemap.
when you're out of memory, remove the last image from the cachemap and download the new.

```
    if (imageCache.get(url) != null) {
        //#debug
        System.out.println("Get cached image from: " + url);

        asyncImage.setImage((Image) imageCache.get(url));
        asyncImage.setQueued(false);
    } else {
        //#debug
        System.out.println("Start download image from:" + url);

        map.put(url, asyncImage);

        ImageDownloadService d = new ImageDownloadService(url, new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

                NetworkEvent n = (NetworkEvent) evt;
                Image image = (Image) n.getMetaData();
                String url = n.getConnectionRequest().getUrl();
                AsyncImage asyncImage = (AsyncImage) ImageManager.this.map.get(url);
                map.put(url, asyncImage);
                asyncImage.setImage(image);
                map.remove(url);
                imageCache.put(url, asyncImage.getImage());
                asyncImage.setQueued(false);
                if (Display.getInstance().getCurrent() instanceof AsyncLoadable) {
                    ((AsyncLoadable) Display.getInstance().getCurrent()).asyncLoaded();
                } else {
                    Display.getInstance().getCurrent().repaint();
                }
                //#debug
                System.out.println("Retrieved image from:" + url);
            }
        });
        d.addResponseCodeListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                NetworkEvent n = (NetworkEvent) evt;
                String url = n.getConnectionRequest().getUrl();
                AsyncImage asyncImage = (AsyncImage) ImageManager.this.map.get(url);
                asyncImage.setQueued(false);
                map.remove(n.getConnectionRequest().getUrl());
                //#debug
                System.out.println("Failed image from:" + url);
            }
        });

        NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueue(d);
```

Comment: The answer is correct so I voted it up. However, you don't need any fancy cache map. We have the EncodedImage class in LWUIT (which is used by default for images loaded from Resources) and it stores the encoded image within it. Which means it will take up far less memory by default. If you couple it with a List which doesn't keep data in RAM you would effectively allow the GC to collect all the bitmap image data on the fly.